# Joomla 4: Redirect to a wished page after front-end login does not work

Tags: joomla-4.x, login, redirect, front-end, profile

I am using a non-published login-menu-item. Calling this item, displays the login-module.

After login, I want to redirect to the homepage, but instead it is displaying the introducing - and featured articles, profile data are shown.

- I changed settings in login-menu-item:
  Choose Login Redirect Type: Menu Item or internal URL - nothing changes.
- I adapted the settings of login-module.
- I tried a different browser to avoid cache-problems.
- I changed the template.
  "System - Privacy Consent" is disabled.
  Same result.

It cannot be *that* complicated, right?

What strikes me: If I choose the home-menu-item (directly after being logged in) no changes happen. The profile data are still being displayed (the profile-page is recalled). I have to click another menu-item first and then I can come back, choosing home-menu-item, and featured articles of homepage etc. are displayed.

Joomla: 4.3.1
PHP: 8.0.20